# Sprites & Layers

Tags: java, layer

so recently I decided to try and make some form of sprite-esque game, similar to the older Final Fantasy games.  I'm mostly doing this as a code learning process rather than using things like RPGMaker to actually create an idea.

The biggest part I'm concerned about are how to properly paint multiple layers of images (such as static Sprites, background images, etc) in a simple way.  While I would normally just test a bunch of things to see rather than asking, I realize there are many (possibly easy) methods of ways to implement any one thing in coding.

What are some ways (or Classes) to implement this?  Preferably a way that is easy to change what layers are where (layer A in front of B... oh wait no B in front of A! at any time)

I do hope that's not too broad of a question.. .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic approach is the [painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm), simply paint layers in reverse order of the distance to the screen (first background, then characters, then foreground for instance).

You have each layer represented by a simple class, something like:

```
public class Layer
{
   List<Sprite> sprites;

   public void draw(Graphics g)
   {
      for (Sprite sprite : sprites)
         sprite.draw(g);
   }
}
```

where a sprite would be:

```
public class Sprite
{
   BufferedImage image;
   float x, y, w, h;

   public void draw(Graphics g)
   {
      g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, (int)(x+w), (int)(y+h), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
   }
}
```

Here, the background would be a layer with a single sprite that is the size of the screen. You can subclass the background layer to achieve effects like parallax.

Finally, your layers would be part of a scene:

```
public class Scene
{
   List<Layer> layers;

   public void draw(Graphics g)
   {
      for (Layer layer : layers)
         layer.draw(g);
   }
}
```

Changing the order of rendering is as simple as changing the order in the 'layers' list in a scene.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for!
Edit:  Just to make sure I completely understand, using the 'layers' field I call the draw function for class (which is each sprite and object that the 'player' can see) which use their own style (depending on the object) to be 'drawn' onto the screen

Comment: @user3650756 Care to rephrase that? I didn't understand, sorry. To summarize: a scene is a list of layers, a layer is a list of sprites. The order of the layers in the scene determines the order in which they will be rendered. Layers must be rendered in reverse order of their distance ("far away first") for the scene to render properly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to put foreground images into a background image? If yes, then the following code will help:

```
public class Image {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage bgImage = ImageIO.read(new File("1.jpg"));
        BufferedImage fgImage =ImageIO.read(new File("2.jpg"));
        BufferedImage overlayedImage = overlay(bgImage, fgImage);
        if (overlayedImage != null) {
             File outputfile = new File("3.jpg");
             ImageIO.write(overlayedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
        } else {}
    }

    public static BufferedImage overlay(BufferedImage bgImage,
            BufferedImage fgImage) {

        Graphics2D g = bgImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(fgImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return bgImage;
    }
}
```